# Как не указывать путь в команде docker-compose и не указывать сам файл yml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, cmd, docker-compose

Попросили написать небольшой сервак на docker, чтобы активировался только по команде docker-compose up.
Для развертывания сервера я пишу в командной строке две команды:

```
`cd d/ E:\Docker\docker1 <--- для указания папки`
`docker-compose -f docker_compose.yml up <--- стартую сервер`
```

Вопросы: 
1) как реализовать это все одной командой `docker-compose up`?
2) после того как я собрал сервер с помощью команды `docker-compose build`, для развертывания сервера на другом компьютере нужна лишь папка docker1(с проектом) и запущенный docker? Я правильно понимаю?
Ps: первый день работаю с docker, не закидывайте помидорами пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) docker-compose у вас должен был быть установлен всесте с докером и добавлен в PATH, поэтому он будет доступен из любой папки, нужно просто указать путь к файлу с конфигом: `docker-compose -f <путь>/docker-compose.yml up` (чтобы не указывать файл, он должен лежать в текущей папке и называться: `docker-compose.yml` или `docker-compose.yaml`).

2) Да (должны стоять docker, docker-compose, сам проект, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml), но тогда вам нужно будет собирать docker образ и на другом компьютере. Можно воспользоваться любым public/private docker-register (например, [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com), если ваш образ содержит приватную информацию, пушить как публичный образ не стоит). Например, у вас есть `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    image: <user name>/test #тут вы указываете имя образа
    container_name: test
```

В итоге на одном компьютере можно вызвать `docker-compose build` -> `docker-compose -f <path>/docker-compose.yml push` (тогда ваш образ будет загружен в registry), а на втором `docker-compose -f <path>/docker-compose.yml pull` -> `docker-compose -f <path>/docker-compose.yml up`. Тогда кроме `docker-compose.yml` файла вам ничего не нужно будет.

Весь выше описанный процесс можно автоматизировать при помощи CI/CD (какой-нибудь github actions, gitlab, azure devops), чтобы на git pull или PR, оно автоматом собирало нужные образы.

Comment: 1)файл лежит лежит в папке с докером, но мне все равно приходится указывать название файла(иначе выводит ошибку). 2)Я правильно понимаю, что если пушить на local registry то я сохраняю образ на своем диске?(При docker-compose build он качал питон ~4 гб. То есть если я перенесу на другой компьютер, я должен всю эту папку(>4гб) перетащить?)

Comment: @Denzel 1) если верить вопросу, то у вас файл называется docker_compose.yml, а должен docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Denzel 2) если этот registry стоит локально, тогда да, но если у вас компьютеры находятся в разным местах/сетях, то пушить в локальный бесполезно. Если вы решили делать через registry, то кроме docker-compose ничего не нужно, а это не больше 1kb, если вы решили пересобирать, то только исходный код и Dockerfile, docker-compose, образ не нужен, он будет скачан автоматически. А чтобы уменьшить размер можно посмотреть на python:slim (~200mb) или alpine (~100mb).